Call a (callback) function in the parent with {children} props
I wanna call a function in the parent that calls a component with {children}, not in the component that actulaly is defining the child component (hard to explain).
Component:
import Parent, { Child } from "./parent";

export default function Component1() {
    return (
        <Parent>
            {/* i don't wanna call the callback from here */}
            <Child prop1='text1-1' prop2='text1-2' />
            <Child prop1='text2-1' prop2='text2-2' />
            <Child prop1='text3-1' prop2='text3-2' />
        </Parent>
    );
}

Parent and child:
import React from "react";

export interface ChildProps {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}

export function Child({ prop1, prop2 }: ChildProps) {
    return (
        <button
            onClick={() => {
                // i wanna call parent function from here
                console.log(`child here with props ${prop1} and ${prop2}`);
            }}>
            <p>{prop1}</p>
            <p>{prop2}</p>
        </button>
    );
}

export default function Parent({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactElement[];
}) {
    const parentCallback = ({ prop1, prop2 }: ChildProps) => {
        // this is the function that i wanna call
        console.log(`parent here with child's props ${prop1} and ${prop2}`);
    };
    return <div>{children}</div>;
}

I think that i have to pass something in {children}, but can't think how. Obvious obs: i'm using typescript

Have you tried https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs or passing function on props? It will able to ref the client props even on grand parent or same level component. Anyway please update with some analogy so we can help you pin point which one is suitable for your problem.

I couldn't understand how to use ref in this case. I'm trying something like intercepting the children and add props to it. Its like the solution proposed by BetterReact Developer, but not exactly yet
